# Jquery - Select images with a class name in viewport

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a webpage with images. When I scroll to the images, I want them to animate. I'm doing like this.

```
$.fn.is_on_screen = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};


$(window).scroll(function(){

                   if( $('.effect').is_on_screen()){
                        $('.effect').addClass('animated bounceIn');
                   } 
                });
```

However, other images with a class ".effect" (not in the viewport) are also animated. Is there any ideas to addClass only to the current images in the viewport with a class named ".effect"?

I have tried this but not working:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

                       if( $('.effect').is_on_screen()){
                            $('.effect', this).addClass('animated bounceIn');
                       } 
                    });
```

Comment: at least use an each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach. First, add the selected elements to a list and keep their current visibility.

```
var settings = {
  throttle: 300
};
var elements = [];

$.fn.viewport = function (options) {
  $.extend(settings, options);

  elements = this;

  return elements.each(function () {
    $(this).data('visible', $(this).visible());
  });
};
```

To check if an element is visible in the viewport, you can use the `getBoundingClientRect` method which returns the coordinates of the element relative to the viewport.

```
$.fn.visible = function () {
  var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var $window = $(window);

  return (
       rect.top <= $window.height()
    && rect.right >= 0
    && rect.bottom >= 0
    && rect.left <= $window.width()
  );
};
```

Now you need to automatically track elements visibility based on scroll position. However, high frequency events such as `scroll` can fire dozens of times per second. Performance can be increased by rate-limiting the number of actual page updates using `setTimeout`.

```
var timer;

$(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      $.each(elements, function () {
        var visible = $(this).visible();

        if (visible) {
          if (!$(this).data('visible')) {
            $(this).data('visible', visible);
            $(this).trigger('enter', event);
          }
        } else if ($(this).data('visible')) {
          $(this).data('visible', visible);
          $(this).trigger('leave', event);
        }
      });

      timer = null;
    }, settings.throttle);
  }
});
```

Usage example:

```
$('div').viewport().on({
  enter: function () {
    $(this).addClass('visible');
  },
  leave: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('visible');
  }
});
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/KYJ4h/.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot @Cătălin Dogaru. You solved my problem.